# Collection type new added elements relation null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Classroom with many Students entities, a student belongs to only 1 classroom

my classroom form:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('students', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => StudentType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ])
;
```

when new students are added, the classroom students collection has the newly added students, while the new students field classroom is NULL, i added event cascade persistence on my classroom entity

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Student::class, mappedBy="classroom", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
```

but i'm still getting error that the classroom field in the new students is NULL

```
Column 'classroom_id' cannot be null
```

does anyone know why ?

Comment: You need to filled the classroom_id data when adding a student

Comment: yes, i can fill manually the classroom field in each student, but i believe it should be done by symfony since he add the student to the classroom, i try to avoid adding the classroom to the student manually

Comment: The room data must comes and filled somewhere. You got to figure it out. Otherwise put a default value

Comment: my classroom is loaded from the database using the paramConverter, and i have my form, which handle the post request sent by the user, for all new students, they are added to the classroom collection, but the field classroom in student remains NULL
in classroom method addStudent i have this line
`$student->setClassroom($this);`
which should set the classroom attribute in student when a student is added to the classroom, but the field classroom in student is remaining NULL

Comment: Is joined column, foreign key configured correctly in database/innoDb? Ex `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="classroom_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

Comment: yes, i have the following
`/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Classroom::class, inversedBy="students")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $classroom;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actualy symfont doesn't call your method `addStudent`, because the option `by_reference` has `true` by default, so to force symfony to use your method, you must set `by_reference` to `false`.

```
->add('students', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => StudentType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ])
```